# Rust string serialization as bytes cross platform compatibility

Tags: rust, utf-8, cross-platform

In Rust, the strings are stored as vector of UTF8 bytes underneath. When calling into `as_bytes` method, the byte representation is returned. Is this byte representation cross platform compatible. If I serialize the a string as bytes to a file in `x86-64`, and then later try to read the string back from the file in `arm`, would I successfully read in the original string? Are there any caveats?

Comment: The internal encoding of rust strings is part of the ABI (so `as_slice` returning utf8-encoded data is part of the language's spec to the extent that it has one). What exactly would you think might not translate between platforms?

Comment: UTF-8 is a way to *interpret* a sequence of bytes. So a linear sequence of bytes encoded in UTF-8 would not be platform-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust strings are encoded as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), which is a common, rigorously defined encoding and is not platform dependent.

Assuming the bytes are unchanged, you can transfer the underlying bytes to different systems without issue, as long as the program reading the bytes decodes them as UTF-8.